# How do you resolve and end pending transaction checks in ethers.js?

Tags: javascript, pending-transactions, txpool, ethers.js

I have the following code scanning the pending transaction pool until my wallet is found:

```js
var scanTxPool = async () => {
    var myWallet = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
    var foundWallet = false;
    provider.on("pending", async (txHash) => {
        if (!foundWallet) {
            provider.getTransaction(txHash).then(async (tx) => {
                if (tx && tx.to) {
                    if (tx.from === myWallet) {
                        console.log('Found my wallet!');
                        foundWallet = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    // do other stuff 
}
```

The code is working great but I have two issues:

1. While the pending transactions are run in the background, execution continues to "do other stuff." How can I make sure that the pending transaction check is awaited before do other stuff is executed?
2. Once my wallet is found from the transaction hash I set `foundWallet` to `true` so the `!foundWallet` check stops it from calling `getTransaction(txHash)`. However, the pending txHash check is still executed indefinitely. How can I cleanly end the pending transaction check once my condition has been met?

Edit: Please see a solution from zemse at the ethers-io repo that still didn't work for me: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/2176#discussioncomment-1487598

Comment: It's watching the pending transactions because you set a listener... why don't you remove the listener? `provider.off("pending")` - https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-off

Comment: why don't you try it... there are two listeners.......

Comment: In that case, you can assign the listener you want to remove to a variable and pass it as the second argument to `provider.off("pending", ....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concept is bit wrong.
`provider.on("pending", ...)` is called listener and it is should be called globaly. So it will listen for `pending` transactions and when find one it would notify you by executing the function passed as second parameter.

```
const completion = (tx) => {
   /* do some stuff */
}

const checkTxHash = async (txHash) => {
    const tx = await provider.getTransaction(txHash)
    if (!tx || !tx.to) return

    if (tx.from === myWallet) {
        console.log('Found my wallet!')
        provider.removeAllListeners()
        completion(tx)
     }
              
}

provider.on("pending", checkTxHash);
```

Comment: this looks like a clean solution Hristo. However, the `provider.on()` call needs to be declared after the `checkTxHash` function to be able to run this and unfortunately once the `myWallet` condition is met the code gets stuck and keeps executing without exiting. The code also is never awaited and constantly runs in the background. Please check the solution from the ethers-io repo that resolves a promise and uses `provider.removeAllListeners()` instead.

Comment: By `constantly runs in the background` you are meaning you want first to get the transaction then to do some other stuff?

Comment: I mean after the wallet is found I want the `checkTxHash` function to complete so I can execute code after `provider.on("pending", checkTxHash);` right now there are two issues. 1. `provider.off("pending")` does not exit the `checkTxHash` function, it keeps running indefinitely and 2. `provider.on()` isn't awaited so code defined after will immediately execute at the same time `checkTxHash` is running

Comment: I you want your method to be awaited you should implement it in promise and resolve this promis like in the github you provided. If you don't want to use promise you can have simple `completion` closure/callback which to handle the success of the function.

Comment: Something like in the answer, I've updated it.